# inconsolata missing to build R vignette

Tags: r, latex, ubuntu-14.04

On ubuntu 14.04 with texlive, checking an R package, for example with `devtools` `check()` would return :

```
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: File `inconsolata.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.276 ^^M

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: @Pascal this first lead to downloading inconsolata.sty from the CTAN which is a bad idea, specially if all you want is having R packages to built without errors

Comment: I never suggested this. Just install a Latex distribution.

Comment: The `inconsolata` package is bundled in the LaTeX distribution [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/). You may consider uninstalling texlive and installing TinyTeX instead.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Installing `texlive-fonts-extra` should take care of it.

You can also (though probably not recommented) tell Rd not to use inconsolata. Just change:

```
\DeclareOption{inconsolata}{\setboolean{Rd@use@inconsolata}{true}}
```

to

```
\DeclareOption{inconsolata}{\setboolean{Rd@use@inconsolata}{false}}
```

in your `Rd.sty` file. On my installation it is at :

```
/usr/share/R/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty
```

but a

```
locate Rd.sty
```

should find it on any system.

Comment: Thanks for the second solution (changing Rd.sty)! incosolate is like 1.7GB and I was on an airport wifi!

Comment: Install the debian package `texlive-fonts-extra` does also solve the reported problem on Ubuntu 18.04.02 (just successfully done)

Comment: absolutely insane i'm installing 1.7Gb of whatever just to get a font 

Comment: Just went through the entire dependency list of `apt` packages _besides_ `texlive-fonts-extra` to see if there is some subset of packages that would work. No! `texlive-fonts-extra` would appear to be minimal

Answer (score 17):

I'm on macOS using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and this worked for me:

```
# LaTeX tools like pdflatex
brew cask install basictex

# Install texlive packages needed to build R package vignettes
sudo tlmgr update --self
sudo tlmgr update --all
sudo tlmgr install titling framed inconsolata
sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended
```

Comment: Works in macOS Mojave for R-4.0.2

Comment: Note that basictex needs to be added to PATH before the command `tlmgr` is available (your equivalent of `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022basic/bin/universal-darwin/:$PATH`)

Answer (score 4):

In Debian, instead of installing the huge `texlive-fonts-extra` package, run this at your shell:

```
tlmgr install inconsolata
updmap-user
```

Comment: Do that (`updmap-user`) may conduct to other errors (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/609807/8639), so I believe it is better to install `texlive-fonts-extra` or maybe other ways to install `inconsolata.sty` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [Travis Continuous Integration
service](https://travis-ci.org/), your problem could be related to the CTAN
mirrors having yet to update.

The issue appears in the [Travis R community forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/latex-error-file-inconsolata-sty-not-found-only-on-osx-when-building-r-package/3261):

> might be related to the recent switch to TexLive-2019 as the LaTeX package manager seems to fail finding inconsolata in the repository.
>
> ...
>
> It looks to me like the mirror chosen was has not updated to 2019, so I think this will resolve itself naturally when the mirrors catch up. If not I can look into it.

In the meantime, I solved it by forcing a previous version of TeXLive with a downgrade to OSX 10.12 in `.travis.yml`:

```
# macOS 10.12 version
osx_image: xcode9.2
```

See [this Travis page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx#macos-version) for the correspondence between XCode and OSX versions and [the original thread in DevOps StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/testing-r-package-on-travis-fails-because-of-texlive-incompatible-versions/8013#8013).

Answer (score 2):

tlmgr gave me a warning about a checksum. However this worked

1. get inconsolata.tds.zip from https://ctan.org/pkg/inconsolata
2. 

```
cd /usr/share/texmf/
sudo unzip  inconsolata.tds.zip 
sudo mktexlsr
```

3. I have had this problem every time I upgrade R. I agree the 1.7GB texlive-fonts-extra is ridiculous for a small file, although I understand that it does give you a choice of several Klingon fonts

this is for texLive on Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I have Mac OSx and the accepted solution didn't work to me.

This was the solution in my case, to install mactex: https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html

Comment: if using basictex see: https://gist.github.com/joethorley/b0766f8d03ec542dd62fcd59c1477f77