# R CMD CHECK and @examples -- check() fails or not depending on a comment

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, roxygen2

I'm using devtools to develop an R package and I'm having trouble with my @examples. I can't believe it, but currently I'm in a place where if I add or remove a comment from the example, it will either check() with no errors, or halt with what seems like an impossible error, or at least one that seems impossible to relate to my code.

This example check()'s with no errors:

```
#' @examples
#' jetsh = read_net(iac_example("jets_sharks.yaml"))
#' jetsh = set_external(jetsh, "Ken", 1.0)
#' jetsh = iac::cycle(jetsh, ncycles = 100)
#' #
#' plot_log(jetsh, roi=c("Ken", "_Ken", "jets", "sharks", "burglar", "bookie"),
#' main="Ken is a burgling Shark")
```

But the version below fails! Note the longer comment about Ken. I've replicated this several times, including restarting the R session between check()'s

```
#' @examples
#' jetsh = read_net(iac_example("jets_sharks.yaml"))
#' jetsh = set_external(jetsh, "Ken", 1.0)
#' jetsh = iac::cycle(jetsh, ncycles = 100)
#' # Ken is a burglar in the Sharks, what is retrieved from his name
#' plot_log(jetsh, roi=c("Ken", "_Ken", "jets", "sharks", "burglar", "bookie"),
#' main="Ken is a burgling Shark")
```

The error message from R CMD CHECK doesn't seem relevant. I've seen scattered reports of similar errors, but not this one:

```
  > base::assign(".dptime", (proc.time() - get(".ptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), pos = "CheckExEnv")
  > base::cat("read_net", base::get(".format_ptime", pos = 'CheckExEnv')(get(".dptime", pos = "CheckExEnv")), "\n", file=base::get(".ExTimings", pos = 'CheckExEnv'), append=TRUE, sep="\t")
  > ### * <FOOTER>
  > ###
  > cleanEx()
  > options(digits = 7L)
  > base::cat("Time elapsed: ", proc.time() - base::g
  + Error: unexpected end of input
  Execution halted
```

The example code runs fine regardless of check() status. Further frustrating is that I have another function using the same @examples, and it has never generated an error during check().

The non-failing version is on git-hub: `'rob-ward-psych/iac'` (`read_net()` in the file `iac_network.R`). Any help running this down is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Between the two functions with identical `@examples` sections, are there differences in what comes immediately after `#' main=...`? That is, are there any other `@`-directives? Are they both simple functions? In your error block, it includes `proc::time() - base:g` (end of line), is that a paste typo or does the actual error code end like that? (My guess is that _that_ might be a hint to internal failures, since I'm inferring it should be `base::get(...)`.)

Comment: The crashing function has a `@returns` (and 3 `@param`), the working one has some `@param` and an `@inheritsDotParam`. That is the full error message I received, it ends abruptly.

Comment: `@return` or `@returns`? It's `@return`.

Comment: It was `@returns`. But I've now changed to `@return` and the behaviour relating to the comment is the same. If the comment line is blank (or just `#' # Ken`) no error, if it is longer (`#' # Ken is a`) check() fails. How can this be??!?.

Comment: Does it change behavior if all of those `@`-params are moved _before_ `@examples`?

Comment: That was the original form of the documentation. I moved the `@examples` in the offending function above all the params and now check() is OK. Does this support a reading that my code/documentation is not the problem and instead might be a check()  bug as suggested by @user2554330

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a `devtools::check` bug.  I get the same error as you using `devtools::check`, but if I build the `.tar.gz` file and then run

```
R CMD check iac_0.1.0.tar.gz
```

I get no error.  If you're using RStudio, you can default to the standard check method in a project option:  uncheck `Build tools | Use devtools package functions if available`.

EDITED to add:

I did some debugging of `devtools::check` to find out what was going wrong.  I don't think this is actually a `devtools::check` bug.  It calls the regular `R CMD check` with the `--timings` option; if I add that option when I call `R CMD check` directly, I get the same error.  It appears to be triggered because the `iac_example()` function has a call to `file.edit()` in its examples section.  I don't know why the form of the comment makes a difference, but it would generally be a good idea to make the call to `file.edit()` conditional on interactive execution, i.e. write

```
if (interactive())
  file.edit(iac_example("what_where.yaml"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replicating! I am in RStudio and very new to the package building process. Can you advise on how to check directly with R CMD? I tried `document()` then `build()`. This creates the .gz file in the folder above the Rproject. That is, the folder `dev/iac` holds the Rproject, the R and man folders, etc. And the .gz file is in `dev`. I go to `dev` and R CMD CHECK, and I get a new fatal error building a pdf (inconsolate.sty not found)

Comment: Followed the advice below to install inconsolata and then the build process described above worked. So this really does seem like a bug in check() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524357/inconsolata-missing-to-build-r-vignette

Comment: I've edited my answer to give another fix to your package code to prevent this issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. Maybe this explains why I had received a number of odd error messages from check(), but always involving a complaint about timing. To confirm, when I use the "if interactive..." form you suggest, check() succeeds without error. When I leave in the file.edit call as `@examples` within the `iac_example` function, I then get my usual error.  R CMD check associates the error with the `@examples` of an entirely different function (`plot_weights`). A tricky one!!